# Change the rows color of tablix report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix report and want to change the color of rows based on condition. I am using following expression in **BackgroundColor** property. But its not working.

```
=IIF(Fields!name.Value= 123456, "White", "Yellow")
```

Whenever there is value in a **column(AccountID)** equals to **123456** than that row should be colored to yellow.

If there any suggestion with this expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things...

Your expression currently says "If AccountID = 123456 then set the background to "White", if not set the background to "Yellow" which is the opposite of what you stated you wanted.

Check that the field name is `name` (it is case sensitive).

Check the the Account ID column is numeric, if not change the string to compare to `"123456"` (enclose it in quotes).